# Black screen when attempting to watch videos on cbs.com

Tags: firefox, video, internet, internet-explorer, video-streaming

As of about three weeks ago, I haven't been able to watch streaming videos from `cbs.com`. I don't remember making any changes to my system configuration around that time.

When I try to load any videos, I briefly see a throbber and then get a black screen. If I mouse over the screen, I do see a play/pause button, progress bar and other buttons, but they do nothing. If I leave the window open for several minutes, the following message eventually appears:

> The video you have requested is either unavailable or is being blocked by an ad blocker installed in your browser.

This seems to be a computer-level issue. Another computer on my network can load CBS videos just fine, but Internet Explorer and Firefox on my computer both fail. I do have NoScript, AdBlockPlus and some other addons installed for Firefox (now version 7, but version 6 when the problem started), but the error persists even if I disable them all. Even if they were to blame, they wouldn't explain why my vanilla Internet Explorer (version 9) fails. My OS is Windows 7.

This seems to be a common issue on the Internet. There are generally two solutions: "disable ad blockers" and "clear your hosts file" (or, at least, exclude `doubleclick.net` from them). Neither one of these fixes worked for me.

What's stopping these videos from loading, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried Safe mode with Networking?  How about as another user?  CBS.COM seems to use Flash for videos (at least the ones I looked at), have you tried removing and reinstalling Flash (ActiveX for IE and plug-in for others)?

Comment: Using safe mode had no effect. Switching users had no effect. I did uninstall and reinstall Flash on both browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is... somewhat resolved. I connected the computer to a network getting service from a different ISP, and the videos played fine.

Ever since I did that, regardless of what network I'm using, the actual show videos work fine although the commercials sometimes don't. A third of the time, commercials load normally; a third of the time, they don't load at all; and the remainder of the time they don't have video or audio but I do have to watch a black screen for about a minute (which is how long commercials usually take when watching CBS shows online).

I know this isn't a particularly useful answer, but it is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My fix for cbs black screen: delete all cookies and history for browser
uninstall priv dog ( not sure this is necessary but I didn't like the way it found it's way onto my machine)
Next, run CCleaner...Analyze, Clean, and do the register.
It's all good now on two browsers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Firefox 7 and CBS videos. In my case I was still able to stream with Chrome. I originally tried disabling all add-ins which did not help. I eventually solved it by deleting all the cookies in Firefox, so at least in my case, it seems to have been caused by a bad cookie.

Comment: Clearing cookies/cache had no effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just coming across this. I had to remove my ad-blocker extension and refresh the page and its working just fine now.